# How to get this using PIVOT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have a table something like this:-

```
DATE        AREA 
01-01-2018   AREA-1
02-01-2018   AREA-1
03-01-2018   AREA-2
```

My Desired Result should be something like this:-

```
AREA    01-01-2018   02-01-2018   03-01-2018
AREA-1    YES           YES          NO
AREA-2    NO            NO          YES
```

How can I get this?

Comment: As you have mentioned, using `Pivot` you can do this. Did you try anything, this is fairly simple..

Comment: I tried but couldn't get.Please help me doing this @Pரதீப்

Comment: Post the query that you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `Pivot`

```
SELECT AREA,
       COALESCE([01-01-2018], 'NO'),
       COALESCE([02-01-2018], 'NO'),
       COALESCE([03-01-2018], 'NO')
FROM   (SELECT *,
               'YES' AS t
        FROM   Yourtable)a
       PIVOT(Max(t)
            FOR DATE IN ([01-01-2018],[02-01-2018],[03-01-2018]) ) pv
```

Even easier method

```
SELECT AREA,
       Max(CASE WHEN date = '01-01-2018' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END),
       Max(CASE WHEN date = '02-01-2018' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END),
       Max(CASE WHEN date = '03-01-2018' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END)
FROM   Yourtable
GROUP  BY AREA
```

Dynamic version

```
DECLARE @col_list    VARCHAR(max)='',
        @select_list VARCHAR(max)='',
        @sql         VARCHAR(max)

SET @col_list = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(DATE)
                       FROM   Yourtable
                       FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
SET @select_list = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',COALESCE(' + Quotename(DATE) + ',''NO'') as ' + Quotename(DATE)
                          FROM   Yourtable
                          FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
SET @sql = '
    SELECT AREA,' + @select_list + '
    FROM   (SELECT *,
                   ''YES'' AS t
            FROM   Yourtable)a
           PIVOT(Max(t)
                FOR DATE IN (' + @col_list + ') ) pv'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Note : Always store dates in `Date` type instead of `varchar`

Comment: Can't we do this dynamically ?

Comment: how can we do that,I'm new to pivot please help me doing this